# Testing Spring RestTemplate for making multipart request on Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, resttemplate

I been digging around for a while but I did not find a proper way to unit test a multipart request from Android using Spring RestTemplate. Any suggestion?
I need to mock the server in order to expect an image and a json. I will then test my requests without one of those parameters, etc..
What is the easiest way for doing so? 
So far I been trying using the MockRestServiceServer class for moking the server but cannot find a way to make it expect parameters.
Hope on your kindness.
Here is the request I would like to test:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartRequest = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object>();

        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        header.add("Authorization",value);

        // creating an HttpEntity for the JSON part
        HttpHeaders jsonHeader = new HttpHeaders();
        jsonHeader.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> jsonHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(json_data, jsonHeader);

        // creating an HttpEntity for the binary part
        HttpHeaders pictureHeader = new HttpHeaders();
        pictureHeader.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        HttpEntity<FileSystemResource> picturePart = new HttpEntity<>(new FileSystemResource(message_data.photo_uri), pictureHeader);

        multipartRequest.add("picPart",picturePart);
        multipartRequest.add("jsonPart",jsonHttpEntity);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(multipartRequest, header);

        String result = restTemplate.postForObject(message_data.server_url, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

For mocking Rest controller class, you can use either:

1) MockMvc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html

2) Restassured : http://rest-assured.io/ 
3) WireMock

For mocking whole server:

1) WireMock: http://wiremock.org/